# Inner join with distinct slow

Tags: sql, performance

I know my query below is just horrible and it takes 2 min to get 10 records (listing table has over 1M records though) but I am not sure whats the better way to write this

I simply just wanna get all the countries that have listings the table that connects countries to listings is province..

```
 ALTER VIEW [dbo].[CountriesWithListings]
 AS
 SELECT     distinct    
    cn.CountryID,
    cn.Code as CountryCode,
    cn.Name as CountryName
FROM         dbo.Countries AS cn

              INNER JOIN dbo.Provinces AS p ON p.CountryID = cn.CountryID
              INNER JOIN dbo.Cities c on c.ProvinceID = p.ProvinceID
              INNER JOIN dbo.Listings AS l ON l.CityID = c.CityID

WHERE l.IsActive = 1 AND l.IsApproved = 1
```

Comment: Do include your database name and version.

Comment: Also you need to include an `EXPLAIN` for the query, number of rows without DISTINCT would be a bare minimum if you suggest in the title the distinct is a problem.

Comment: Remove distinct, select from dbo.Countries only, and move the rest to an EXISTS.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming you have the appropriate indices in place, using `distinct` is expensive.  You should be able to get better performance using `exists`:

```
SELECT     
    cn.CountryID,
    cn.Code as CountryCode,
    cn.Name as CountryName
FROM dbo.Countries AS cn
WHERE EXISTS (
    SELECT 1
    FROM dbo.Provinces AS p
              INNER JOIN dbo.Cities c on c.ProvinceID = p.ProvinceID
              INNER JOIN dbo.Listings AS l ON l.CityID = c.CityID
    WHERE p.CountryID = cn.CountryID
        AND l.IsActive = 1 
        AND l.IsApproved = 1
)
```

Comment: This worked perfectly, will mark the answer in 8 min when it allows me to.

Answer (score 0):

Is the listing table indexed? If it has like 1M entries, it would be good to index it first and check the performance after that. Your query is not that complex

Answer (score 0):

The performance of the query also depends on the indexes that exist in you environment and the column you are using.

Try this...

```
SELECT cn.CountryID
    ,MIN(cn.Code) AS CountryCode
    ,MIN(cn.NAME) AS CountryName
FROM dbo.Countries AS cn
INNER JOIN dbo.Provinces AS p ON p.CountryID = cn.CountryID
INNER JOIN dbo.Cities c ON c.ProvinceID = p.ProvinceID
INNER JOIN dbo.Listings AS l ON l.CityID = c.CityID
WHERE l.IsActive = 1
    AND l.IsApproved = 1
GROUP BY cn.CountryID
```

Comment: Why both DISTINCT and GROUP BY?

Comment: @jarlh Didnt change that part of the old code while reusing it. Thanks

Comment: Your welcome! (Don't think it matters, should be optimized, but it looks better this way!)

Answer (score 0):

Without adding indexing or other performance tuning this query should run faster:

```
ALTER VIEW [dbo].[CountriesWithListings]
AS
    SELECT cn.CountryID, cn.Code as CountryCode, cn.Name as CountryName
    FROM dbo.Countries AS cn
    WHERE cn.CountryID IN
    (
        SELECT p.CountryId FROM dbo.Provinces
        INNER JOIN dbo.Cities c on c.ProvinceID = p.ProvinceID
        INNER JOIN dbo.Listings AS l ON l.CityID = c.CityID
        WHERE l.IsActive = 1 AND l.IsApproved = 1
    )
```